# Constantly monitoring a TCP streaming feed for data in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I am writing a Python script in Python 3.5, I have a host and port and what I am trying to do is create the script so that it is constantly monitoring the provided host for data. The data is distributed through the TCP streaming feed in an xml format with a tag marking the start and end of the event.

So what I am trying to do is basically monitor the TCP feed for new events which are marked between an xml start and end tag, then retrieve the event and handle it accordingly in my script. In addition, ideally I would need to have access to new data in the feed within milliseconds.

The feed is a government feed that distributes alerts, the feed is streaming1.naad-adna.pelmorex.com and the port is 8080, what I want to do is monitor this feed for new alerts and then be able to access the alerts and handle them accordingly in Python. The feed sends a heartbeat every minute to indicate the connection is alive.

I believe the best option would be to make use of Sockets though I am unsure of how to implement them in this specific use case. I do not have much experience with TCP feeds, and I was unable to find much online pertaining to how to handle a TCP feed in Python under my specific use case, I am able to handle the xml though once I am able to figure out how to pull it from the TCP feed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "TCP feed" isn't a term of art in computer networking. Can you be more precise in your question?

Comment: @Robᵩ I have added further details to the post, sorry about not being that clear the first time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several technical challenges presented in your question.

First, is the simple matter of connecting to the server and retrieving the data. As you can see in `connect()` below, that is pretty simple, just create a socket (`s = socket.socket()`) and connect it (`s.connect(('hostname', port_number))`).

The next problem is retrieving the data in a useful form. The socket natively provides `.recv()`, but I wanted something with a file-like interface. The socket module provides a method unique to Python: `.makefile()`. (`return s.makefile('rb')`)

Now we get to the hard part. XML documents are typically stored one document per file, or one document per TCP transmission. Thus the end of the document is easily discovered by an end of file indication, or by a `Content-Length:` header. Consequently, none of the Python XML API have a mechanism for dealing with multiple XML documents in one file, or in one string. I wrote `xml_partition()` to solve that problem. `xml_partition()` consumes data from a file-like object and yields each XML document from the stream. (Note: the XML documents must be pressed together. No whitespace is allowed after the final `>`).

Finally, there is a short test program (`alerts()`) which connects to the stream and reads a few of the XML documents, storing each into its own file.

Here, in its entirety, is a program for downloading emergency alerts from the National Alert Aggregation & Dissemination System from Pelmorex.

```
import socket
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def connect():
    'Connect to pelmorex data stream and return a file-like object'
    # Set up the socket
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(('streaming1.naad-adna.pelmorex.com', 8080))
    return s.makefile('rb')

# We have to consume the XML data in bits and pieces
# so that we can stop precisely at the boundary between
# streamed XML documents. This function ensures that
# nothing follows a '>' in any XML fragment.
def partition(s, pattern):
    'Consume a file-like object, and yield parts defined by pattern'
    data = s.read(2048)
    while data:
        left, middle, data = data.partition(pattern)
        while left or middle:
            yield left
            yield middle
            left, middle, data = data.partition(pattern)
        data = s.read(2048)

# Split the incoming XML stream into fragments (much smaller
# than an XML document.) The end of each XML document
# is guaranteed to align with the end of a fragment.
# Use an XML parser to determine the actual end of
# a document.  Whenever the parser signals the end
# of an XML document, yield what we have so far and
# start a new parser.
def xml_partition(s):
    'Read multiple XML documents from one data stream'
    parser = None
    for part in partition(s, b'>'):
        if parser is None:
            parser = ET.XMLPullParser(['start', 'end'])
            starts = ends = 0
            xml = []
        xml.append(part)
        parser.feed(part)
        for event, elem in parser.read_events():
            starts += event == "start"
            ends += event == "end"
            if starts == ends > 0:
                # We have reached the end of the XML doc
                parser.close()
                parser = None
                yield b''.join(xml)

# Typical usage:
def alerts():
    for i, xml in enumerate(xml_partition(connect())):
        # The XML is a bytes object that contains the undecoded
        # XML stream. You'll probably want to parse it and
        # somehow display the alert.

        # I'm just saving it to a file.
        with open('alert%d.xml' % i, 'wb') as fp:
            fp.write(xml)
        if i == 3:
            break

def test():
    # A test function that uses multiple XML documents in one
    # file. This avoids the wait for a natural-disaster alert.
    with open('multi.xml', 'rb') as fp:
        print(list(xml_partition(fp)))

alerts()
```